# Can I move the scroll bar on a div to the left, without reversing the order of the elements of the table inside it?

Tags: html

I got a div with a scroll bar containing a table. I want to have the scroll bar on the left of the div, but without reversing the order of the elements in the table.

the way it looks like now is (simplified):

```
<div dir="rtl">
   <table>
   ... table stuff goes here.
   </table>
</div>
```

now, i've tried using `<table dir="ltr">` but it doesn't work and I can't just reverse the order of the elements because then the punctuation is moved to the left. Is there any way to do this wihout adding a custom scroll bar?

Comment: So you just want to show the scroll bar on the left? That's not possible without using a script, like, http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html and using `scrollbarOnLeft`

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already. Try setting your div CSS like this. It should work then.

```
div {
overflow:scroll;
}
```

Or this if you want inline.

```
<div dir="rtl" style="overflow:scroll">
```